# iOS app submission - timed out (-1001,2)

Tags: ios, xcode

I do have this error message while trying to submit an app to the app store

[image: app store]

Comment: The developer portal is currently unavailable (most probably due to the upcoming WWDC) with a "We'll be back soon" message, so I guess that is the reason that the submission is failing...

Comment: This error message is almost self-explanatory then :/ Thanks  Alladinian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [Apple's System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/), check the [iTunes Connect Twitter Account](https://twitter.com/itcstatus), or just [search Twitter for iTunes Connect](https://twitter.com/search?q=iTunesConnect) to find out whether the system is down.

I find that system issues will show up in the tweets of folks using it first (probably because it's not clear how you're supposed to report an outage).

Answer (score 0):

Because of the maintenance work of apple site, you can not submit app into iTunes.