# iTunes Connect submit for review - Your app information could not be saved. Try again

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I get this error message when trying to submit a new version of my app for review:

[image]

While I've seen other threads about this error message, the solutions presented haven't worked for me and I haven't seen any mentions of the actual server error message I get. iTunes Connect responds with the following error message:

`Error converting JSON string to object: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.apple.jingle.label.content.purple.to.LCSubmitForReviewTO] from JSON integral number; no single-int-arg constructor/factory method`

**Request details:**

```
Remote Address:23.1.186.88:443
Request URL:https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/123456789/version/submit/complete
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

**Full JSON response:**

```
{
    "data":null,
    "messages": {
        "warn":null,
        "error":[
             "Error converting JSON string to object: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class com.apple.jingle.label.content.purple.to.LCSubmitForReviewTO] from JSON integral number; no single-int-arg constructor/factory method"
        ],
        "info":null
    },
    "statusCode":"ERROR"
}
```

I've tried clearing all cookies, and also changing to another browser, and I've also tried removing the build and adding it again, but I get the same issue regardless. Has anyone else had this exact problem? Did anyone find a way around it?

Comment: Same problems here....

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. Same response. I've tested it on Chrome on Win7 and Safari/Firefox/Chrome on OS X (El Capitan). So it's not a browser issue. I'm also seeing similar reports on the Apple forums abut this issue: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26494. Could it be an issue with the iTunes Connect service?

Comment: Same here. Seems to be a new bug in iTunes Connect. Please file a radar and contact the iTunes Connect support to let them know this problem is pressuring many people. May I ask when exactly you're getting the error message? For me it's after the export compliance question.

Comment: I faced the same issue today. Probably itunesconnect is f**ked up again. Thanks for posting the JSON error response, so that I can find this thread and figure out that the problem is not just with my account!!!

Comment: I had this problem too for quite some time. But now it seems that they fixed it.

Comment: Same problem here still. Just filed a radar report. I encourage everyone who has this issue to do the same, as Apple weights duplicative bug reports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS app submission - timed out (-1001,2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710831/ios-app-submission-timed-out-1001-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried submitting my app again, after 12 hours of being unable to. It worked!

Comment: it looks like apple has addressed their issue

Comment: Thanks for bringing the good news, works for me now too! As Einstein said: Insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results. Well, 98% of all iTunes Connect issues seem to be solved using some good old insanity ;)